# Core Plot Thread Error - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400002122)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

My am using Core Plot Framework version 2 in my app. I am facing error following method "plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt" CPTDecimalFromInt returning null value.

Core Plot space Creation

```
//Add plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

// coreplot change
plotSpace.delegate = self;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0.0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromInt(10)];    
plotSpace.yRange  = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                 length:CPTDecimalFromInt([self getMaxYValue])];*/
```

Getting Crash in Below code

```
+ (instancetype)plotRangeWithLocation:(NSNumber *)loc length:(NSNumber *)len {
    return [[self alloc] initWithLocation:loc length:len];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Plot API changed slightly in 2.0. The `+plotRangeWithLocation:length:` method now takes `NSNumber` objects as parameters instead of `NSDecimal` values.

See this [wiki page](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Core-Plot-API-Changes-Between-Versions-1.x-and-2.x) for a summary of the changes between 1.x and 2.0.